# Argument of type '{ query: {}; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFn'

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am building an angular app where I have to upload and retrieve images from firebase databse. I am successfully being able to upload the images, but for retrieval I have the following bit of code in

### service.ts

```
getFileUploads(query = {}) {
this.fileUploads = this.db.list(this.basePath, {
  query: query
});
return this.fileUploads
}
```

I keep getting the error

> Argument of type '{ query: {}; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFn'.
>
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'query' does not exist in type 'QueryFn'.

The following is the entire service.ts code

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

import {FileUpload} from '../profile/fileupload';

@Injectable()
export class UploadFileService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  private basePath = '/uploads';
  fileUploads: AngularFireList<FileUpload[]>;

  pushFileToStorage(fileUpload: FileUpload, progress: {percentage: number}) 
 {
const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${fileUpload.file.name}`).put(fileUpload.file);

uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
  (snapshot) => {
    // in progress
    const snap = snapshot as firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot
    progress.percentage = Math.round((snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100)
  },
  (error) => {
    // fail
    console.log(error)
  },
  () => {
    // success
    fileUpload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL
    fileUpload.name = fileUpload.file.name
    this.saveFileData(fileUpload)
  }
);
}

 private saveFileData(fileUpload: FileUpload) {
  this.db.list(`${this.basePath}/`).push(fileUpload);
}

 getFileUploads(query = {}) {
this.fileUploads = this.db.list(this.basePath, {
  query: query
});
return this.fileUploads;
}
}
```

and the following is the component.ts for the component where I want to display the image

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemService } from '../services/item.service';
import {FileUpload} from '../profile/fileupload';
import {UploadFileService} from '../services/upload-file.service';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  fileUploads: AngularFireList<FileUpload[]>;

  constructor(private uploadService: UploadFileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fileUploads = this.uploadService.getFileUploads({l});
  }
}
```

Comment: what version you are using

Comment: @waploaj Angular5. Do I have to import anything?

Comment: did you `import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';`

Comment: @waploaj Yes I have

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for list querying](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md) with angularfire2 shows that the second parameter to the `list()` method should be a function and not an object.

Specifically, the method definition for `list()` from [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/database/database.ts) shows that it is of the type

```
list<T>(pathOrRef: PathReference, queryFn?: QueryFn): AngularFireList<T>
```

and that `QueryFn` (defined [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/database/interfaces.ts)) is of the type

```
type QueryFn = (ref: DatabaseReference) => DatabaseQuery;
```

So the error is correct, that it is expecting you to pass a function as the second parameter and not an object.

Since your own `query` parameter does not have a type definition that you have posted here, it's hard for me to tell exactly what you are thinking a caller of your `getFileUploads` method would pass in, but it's likely that you need some sort of transformation between that object type and the `QueryFn` type that angularfire is expecting.

Comment: I have now added more related code in the question. If you could please have a look at it.